# Reset js countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I'm not a js developer, more of graphic designer wannabe developer, I'm creating a website for a friend and I need to make the countdown reset after it reaches the deadline.

I've got this code from Matt Smith on Codepen and it works really well (you can have a look https://m13m.webflow.io/), but unfortunately the timer goes negative and I want it to repeat itself.

How could I do that?

Thank you very much!

```
 <script>
// Original Pen by Matt Smith 
const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date('Mar 19, 2022 22:28:00').getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function() {

      let now = new Date().getTime(),
          distance = countDown - now;

      document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
        document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
        document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
        document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
      
      //do something later when date is reached
      //if (distance < 0) {
      //  clearInterval(x);
      //  'IT'S MY BIRTHDAY!;
      //}

    }, second)
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code look good. You have to check if distance lower as 0 then clear the timer and print you BDay text.

```js
// Original Pen by Matt Smith 
const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

let countDown = new Date('Mar 19, 2022 22:28:00').getTime();
let x = setInterval(function() {
  let now = new Date().getTime();
  let distance = countDown - now;
  if (distance < 0) {    
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "HAPPY BDAY"    
    clearInterval(x);
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day));
  document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour));
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute));
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
  
  

    }, second)
```

```html
<div id="days"></div>
<div id="hours"></div>
<div id="minutes"></div>
<div id="seconds"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

#### Update (Timer will start again)

```js
// Original Pen by Matt Smith 
const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;
let round = 1;
const diff = 1; // set timediff in minutes
//let countDown = new Date('Mar 19, 2022 22:28:00').getTime();
let countDown = new Date(new Date().getTime() + diff*60000);
let x = setInterval(function() {
  let now = new Date().getTime();
  let distance = countDown - now;
  if (distance < 0) {    
    countDown = new Date(new Date().getTime() + diff*60000);
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "HAPPY BDAY" + ' Round => ' + (round++)
  }
  document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day));
  document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour));
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute));
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
  
}, second)
```

```html
<div id="days"></div>
<div id="hours"></div>
<div id="minutes"></div>
<div id="seconds"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to delete that comment from there. I do not want it to show a message, I want the countdown to repeat itself when it reaches 0.

Comment: @AlexandruConstantin I updated my answer! Now will (repeat / start again) after the coundown is finished. Timer is 1 minutes and you can set the timer if you set the var `diff` in the code.

Comment: @AlexandruConstantin Thank you for your Feedback! You welcome. If you found that my answer was helpful it would be nice if you can accept answer. If you found it was good you can also  upvote :-) Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way I could make it reset every 3 hours while keeping the countdown running when the page is refreshed (like if the user opens the page at 2:59:00 and refreshes it until 2 minutes, the countdown should show 2:57:00)? 

Thank you very much for the help until now!