# Reset js countdown timer and keep it running on page refresh

Tags: javascript, countdown, countdowntimer

I want to update this code from here:
[Reset js countdown timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71541939/reset-js-countdown-timer)

to reset every 3 hours, but to also keep running when the user reloads the page - like if the user opens the page at 0:2:57:00 and the user refreshes the page in two minutes the countdown should show 0:2:55:00

Here is the code:

```
<script>
const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 60;
let round = 1;
const diff = 180 ; // set timediff in minutes
//let countDown = new Date('Mar 19, 2022 22:28:00').getTime();
let countDown = new Date(new Date('Apr 1, 2022 18:04').getTime() + diff*60000);
let x = setInterval(function() {
  let now = new Date().getTime();
  let distance = countDown - now;
  if (distance < 0) {    
   const diff = 180
   
  }

  document.getElementById('days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day));
  document.getElementById('hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour));
  document.getElementById('minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute));
  document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
  
   document.getElementById('dayz').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day));
  document.getElementById('hourz').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour));
  document.getElementById('minutez').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute));
  document.getElementById('secondz').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
  
}, second)
</script>
```

I don't know how to fix it. I've searched all the internet!

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Refreshing the page means that any state in your script is lost. So you need to find a way to make state persist between page refreshes. You may look up LocalStorage, among other browser storage APIs to store the start time of your timer. Then you can extract the start time once you refresh your page and calculate the remaining time and start counting.

Comment: A day is 24 hours, not 60